# Open a file in ProjectedFS with GENERIC_ALL access (Projected File System)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, filesystems, internals

I've create example application using [Projected File System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/projfs/projected-file-system)

I've implement all necessary functions and it works well when I open a file from projected FS with GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE access, but when I'm trying to use GENERIC_ALL I'm getting access denied error.

What is possible reason of getting `access denied` error?
I'm getting the error when a file is already copied to projected filesystem.

CODE:

```
HANDLE fHandle = CreateFile(path_to_file_in_projected_fs, GENERIC_ALL, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

Expected result: valid file handle.

Actual result: invalid handle with access denied error (via GetLastError())

P.S. GENERIC_READ_WRITE_EXECUTE works fine

```
HANDLE fHandle = CreateFile(path_to_file_in_projected_fs, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Please post your code, example input, and expected output.

Comment: @JL2210 edited, just add client code from where I'm tried to access projected fs

Comment: Can you give the path to the file and ensure that you have read/write permissions to it?

Comment: maybe not having full permission is the reason why it fails to get a GENERIC_ALL access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is GENERIC_ALL equivalent to GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_EXECUTE?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170310-00/?p=95705)
`GENERIC_ALL` means "every possible level of access" (for files, this has the name `FILE_ALL_ACCESS`). It's not just `GENERIC_EXECUTE` + `GENERIC_WRITE` + `GENERIC_READ`, `GENERIC_ALL` contains things such as `DELETE`, `WRITE_DAC` (to change permissions) and `WRITE_OWNER` (to change owner). You could check the [File Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-security-and-access-rights) for the access of `FILE_GENERIC_*`.

You can try to add permissions one by one from GENERIC_READ+WRITE+EXECUTE to see which permissions cause the issue.
However, **you should request only the level of access that actually need**.

Comment: @drake-wu-msft https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55830648/copy-files-from-source-with-security-descriptor-projfs